# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Using same IP for outbound

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I currently have an elastic beanstalk setup in AWS  currently whenever i make API calls it is coming from the EC2 instance's external IP.  is there a way to have all servers in that group use the same IP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your EC2 instances in private subnets and direct all outbound traffic through a NAT. This way, all outbound connections appear to come from the NAT's IP address.

See the following for more information. It's a different problem, but the NAT solution is the same.

[How do you allocate STATIC addresses to an EBS (beanstalk) within a VPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277453/how-do-you-allocate-static-addresses-to-an-ebs-beanstalk-within-a-vpc)

Note, for security, you should follow this architecture anyways. When using ELB, don't have your EC2 instances in a public subnet.